# How to move spcific apps to/from sd card using ADB?

Tags: android, adb, android-sdcard

### Background

It is possible to set the default installation to the SD card by using (based on [**this link**](http://techgage.com/article/moving_your_non-movable_android_apps_to_an_sd_card/)) :

for pre- API14 :

```
adb shell pm setInstallLocation 2
```

for API 14 and above:

```
adb shell pm set-install-location 2 (Android 4.x)
```

### The problem

This only works for newly installed apps (or you just go manually over each of them and set it there), but I would like to know how to re-install an already installed app into the SD card (and also back to the internal storage).

### What I've tried

I tried to read the commands available via ADB, and tried to run the next command:

```
adb shell pm install -s -r -i com.example.test
```

But it didn't work

### The question

Suppose an app is already installed on the internal storage (or the SD card), how can I use ADB to re-install it to the SD card (or the internal) ?

Comment: Wish more questions are asked that way...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski in what way? the titles? I wish I could make a template since it's annoying to type it each time. if the question is too short i don't even bother.

Comment: In the way that let anyone clearly understand what the problem is and how you tried to solve the problem yourself prior asking here. I am simply feed up with all this crappy "questions" containing huge amount of messy code OP clearly did not even tried to understand nor even tried to read i.e. stacktrace.

Comment: most of the questions I ask are in this manner. only short ones that I really can't give any information I make super short and clear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, need to provide the location of the APK rather than the package name.

Following worked on my end for [VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon) that I installed from Play Store and was originally located in internal storage:

```
$ adb shell pm install -s -r /data/app/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1.apk
    pkg: /data/app/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1.apk
Success
$
```

And moving back to internal storage:

```
$ adb shell pm install -f -r /mnt/asec/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1/pkg.apk
    pkg: /mnt/asec/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1/pkg.apk
Success
$
```

### Update 1

Following are respective commands with `-i: specify the installer package name` option.

Move to SD card:

```
$ adb shell pm install -i "com.android.vending" -s -r /data/app/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1.apk
    pkg: /data/app/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1.apk
Success
```

Move to internal storage:

```
$ adb shell pm install -i "com.android.vending" -f -r /mnt/asec/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1/pkg.apk
    pkg: /mnt/asec/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1/pkg.apk
Success
```

### Update 2

Using `-i` is optional, but if it is not used the installer information is lost during movement:

```
$ adb shell pm list packages -3 -i
package:org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon  installer=com.android.vending

$ adb shell pm install -s -r /data/app/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1.apk
    pkg: /data/app/org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon-1.apk
Success

$ adb shell pm list packages -3 -i
package:org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon  installer=null
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but when I type "adb shell pm" , it says: "-i: specify the installer package name." . why can't it work using it?

Comment: Well, maybe you should specify the installer name when using `-i` option? :) Do you really need to use `-i`?

Comment: no but what is written there is misleading. I wonder why they need it if I give them the APK file anyway... I mean , why should I even use the "-i" ?

Comment: I see. Please see *Update 2*

Comment: That's even weirder. Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: Say, does it require a certain Android version in order to work?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any reliable means of checking this on real targets. However, except for `-3` and `-i` options of `pm list packages`, the rest is working on emulator with Android 2.3.3.

Comment: I see. How come when I launch it on my Android 4.4 device, I get : "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_URI]" ? and when I enter to to path of the APK file (using "cd ") and use this command, I get : "Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE] " ? It doesn't make sense, as I have plenty of space on the sd card.

Comment: That could be an OEM specific bug, which device are you talking about? I have seen similar behavior on certain Samsung Tabs...

Comment: It's on an I9300 (Galaxy S3), but it's an AOSP rom (OmniRom). why shouldn't it work on some OEMs ? it's available for such a long time, no? Also, i've tried out some apps that claim to move apps to the sd card, but none do it. Instead, they just send you to manage the app...

Comment: As far as I can see "insufficient storage" error is reported by the underlying file system hooks. The PM feature itself is present at least since Android 2.3.3. Probably, being an AOSP based ROM, OmniRom assumes the target has no real external storage support and has no physical mount point for SD card. Hence the false "insufficient storage" report.

Comment: But I do have an SD card. A real one. do all AOSP based roms have this issue? is it possible to identify this issue on such roms?

Comment: I've now tested it on CM rom . same thing happens there too. Do you think that if I move to the stock rom (or a stock based rom), it will allow me to do it ?

Comment: I've also tried it on an emulator, and it gives me the next error: WARNING: linker: " libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.... Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR] " . Why does it occur? I've tried it on multiple apps...

Comment: I am seeing similar errors both on stock Galaxy S3 (`INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`) and AVD for Nexus 5 (`INSTALL_FAILED_CONTAINER_ERROR`). Looks like either Google has silently deprecated this feature or there is bug in the later versions of Android. Sorry for not being able to give more detailed answer. This requires digging in the git history which I am not able to do at this moment.

Comment: Do you think there is a way to check if this feature is available on the current OS ? Meaning, if a device cannot use this feature, I will know that it cannot?